# Dataloader Upserting Child Account to Parent Account using External ID:

Tags: data-loader, account, externalid, child-to-parent

I'm using Dataloader to Upsert a Child Account to Parent Account using an external ID.

When the Upsert is complete, it's creating a new account, **it's not not connecting the Child Account to the Parent Account.**

((See Answer Below))

Comment: please don't vandalize your own question. Either physically delete your question or leave it for others to benefit.

Comment: All the more important that your question stays up.

Comment: You got an answer right below. I am having a hard time following your question since your screenshots are very small and blurred out... plus the text is not clear to me.

Comment: Steve, I think there's a mismatch in expectations here that I'd like to try to clear up. SFSE is a community knowledge base with contributors around the world. Contributors cannot always respond to comments in real time, or at all, although it's great when folks can do so. "Bumping" is not a thing here (edits to raise questions are _strongly_ discouraged), but you are more than welcome to [edit] in order to add information and details to help the community understand the issue and provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should mark external id as unique.

Secondly, in the 3rd screen, field mapping should be on 2 fields External_Id__c and Parent’s External_Id__c where you have specified the id and external_id__c.

Thats why the records are not matched during upsert.

Answer (score 0):

How to Upsert Child Accounts to Parent Accounts Using Dataloader:

[image]